# tcpdumpで他者間の通信をキャプチャしたいです

Tags: linux, tcpdump

とても初歩的な質問ですがよろしくお願いします。

tcpdumpで自分以外のホスト間の通信が取れません。

例としまして、

host1:192.168.1.10
host2:192.168.1.20
host3:192.168.1.30

というIPアドレスであった場合、host2からhost3へのpingをhost1がキャプチャすることは可能でしょうか？

「tcpdump host 192.168.2.10」や、「tcpdump src host 192.168.2.10 and dst host 192.168.3.10」と打ってもhost1サーバは自ホストへの通信以外まったく反応しません。

オプション指定しない限りプロミスキャスモードで動くというように聞きましたが、そもそも仕組みを勘違いしていますか？

Comment: 3台のホストはどのようにつないでいますか？ 単純にスイッチングハブでつないだだけだと、宛先と関係ないホストにはパケットが流れません。他者間の通信をキャプチャするには、「ポートミラーリング」対応のハブを利用して、然るべき設定を行うことでキャプチャできるようになります。

Answer (score 1):

スイッチングHUBなどでつないでる場合は基本通信当事者のパケットしか通しません
すべてをバカHUB（リピーターHUB）で繋げばいいんですが。